# PHP get request returning false

Tags: php, api, get

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php");

var_dump($data);
```

I keep getting false when sending this get request, anyone have an idea why?

It works just fine with a simple php script I wrote hosted from the same domain, might that be the issue,  how do I go about sending a get request to this API if that is the case?

I tried using curl as well with the same result.  It works with my test script but not the API.

Comment: i think you need to pass some reference variable to get and process data in API such as `get.php?some_data=some_value` and can you post `get.php` code

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so.  Try sending a http get request by simply navigating to the URL as is in your browser and you will see it displays a random word.  (Unless I'm misunderstanding how that works).  I would post the get.php code if I could, but it's not posted as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RamRaider hmm do you have any kind of header setting or is your php script just those two lines?

Comment: Simply the two lines you posted above return a random word each time

Comment: @RamRaider Well that's odd.... I get bool(false) from the var_dump every time.  Could it have something to do with the server my PHP script is hosted on?  It's hosted by arvixe, the server is in the U.S.

Comment: I guess it could @john Carter. From the PHP manual - "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the various comments above, the code originally posted works fine for me but not for the OP - most likely due to a restriction placed upon various standard PHP functions by the webhost. As an alternative, cURL should be able to retrieve the content unless a similar restriction has been placed on standard curl functions too.

```
    $url='http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php';

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl-wordfetcher' );
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    if( curl_errno( $ch ) ) echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    print_r( $result );
```

Comment: I tried the above cURL code.  When the url is set to a php hosted on the same sever it works fine (like the file_get_contents strategy above) but when using the externally hosted php file as the url the following error is returned:     `Curl error: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`                     I'll try contacting my webhost to see if this is due to a restriction on their part and accept your answer if that is the case, it sounds like it though. (Thanks a lot btw!)

Comment: It was indeed a restriction placed by the webhost.  After talking to them they have since lifted it.  Works now, thanks!